# Regular Expression that matchis something or nothing

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to find a value between two HTML tags i.e: `<td></td>`

There can either be a word character `\w` or nothing (not even a space between the `><` closing an opening bracket.

So I am trying this `/<td>[\w{1,}|]<\/td>/` but it is not working.

This is for php, and yes, I am well aware of some people warning against parsing HTML with regular expressions ;) ...

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Just replace `[]` with `()`. https://regex101.com/r/4Cy2xZ/3. Your regex is not ideal but it should work with that change.

Answer (score 1):

```
/<td>\w*<\/td>/
```

If you are trying to have matching groups, you need parentheses not brackets:

```
/<td>(\w*)<\/td>/
```

To match "nothing", just make the term optional with an `*`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find a value between two html tags.
Please use bellow regex

```
(?<td>)(\w*)(?=<\/td>)
```

It just match only the word or nothing in between `<td></td>`

https://regex101.com/r/4Cy2xZ/1

Comment: Where do you look for the opening tag ?